# Modifying default function to return one extra key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) for webpage.I want to get a json variable which represents the widget position and html content on it.The default [Serialize](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/serialize.html) function returns a json but it does not returns html content on the widgets.
How can I alter the original function

From library the default serialize function is as follows:

```
/**
     * Returns a serialized array of the widgets in the grid.
     *
     * @method serialize
     * @param {HTMLElement} [$widgets] The collection of jQuery wrapped
     *  HTMLElements you want to serialize. If no argument is passed all widgets
     *  will be serialized.
     * @return {Array} Returns an Array of Objects with the data specified in
     *  the serialize_params option.
     */
    fn.serialize = function ($widgets) {
        $widgets || ($widgets = this.$widgets);
        var result = [];
        $widgets.each($.proxy(function (i, widget) {
            var $w = $(widget);
            if (typeof($w.coords().grid) !== 'undefined') {
                result.push(this.options.serialize_params($w, $w.coords().grid));
            }
        }, this));
        return result;
    };
```

And serialize_params is as follows

```
serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
                    return {
                        col: wgd.col,
                        row: wgd.row,
                        size_x: wgd.size_x,
                        size_y: wgd.size_y
                    };
```

I just want something like this may be

```
serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
                    return {
                        col: wgd.col,
                        row: wgd.row,
                        size_x: wgd.size_x,
                        size_y: wgd.size_y
                        html: wgd.html content
                    };
```

I am just not sure how to extract the html content from the

```
<textarea>
```

The default JSON is of form

```
[{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":2,"size_y":2},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]
```

JSON I want should be something of form

```
[{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":2,"size_y":2,"html":"Some long text,Some long text"},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":2, "html":"Some long text,Some long text"},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1,"html":"Some long text,Some long text"}]
```

Basically in the fiddle link I want to store the value of text area as an additional key value pair.

```
"html":"Text from <textarea>"
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvt0hf7r/4/)

Comment: welcome back NewBie :-)

Comment: Hehehehe, Yeah Randy Casburn :)

Comment: Sorry for delay - here you go. Try not to over think these problems. There is a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it yourself. There is no reason to modify the API to do this. Here is the solution:

```
$('.js-seralize').on('click', function () {
    var s = gridster.serialize();
    $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el)=>{ // grab the grid elements
       s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values
    });
    $('#log').val(JSON.stringify(s));
})
```

Comment: Thanks again for this approach.Understanding basic function was a herculean task then I would have thought of modifying it

Comment: Glad to help...again :-)

Comment: @NewBie - Would like to complement you on your questions -they are very well written and you make it easy to zero in on your issue. thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks. I am glad I can express my problem in a better way so that people like you can help me out and in turn other people who may benefit with question and answer.In all making this community a better place :)

Comment: Iif I write some content in the text area in grids(or remove any content) I want the updated one  serialize.How can we do that

Comment: I have made a question for it please have a look over it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217637/capturing-the-updated-content-from-text-are-in-json-variable

Comment: Please if possible can you go over this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3crspqL5/40/ to check the problem which is addressed in the question mentioned prior to this comment