# Capturing the updated content from text are in JSON variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
 var gridster;

 $(function() {

   gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
     widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
     widget_margins: [5, 5]
   }).data('gridster');

   $('.js-seralize').on('click', function() {
     var s = gridster.serialize();
     $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
       s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values
     });
     $('#log').val(JSON.stringify(s));
   })

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/assets/css/demo.css"></script>

<script src="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.css"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.js"></script>

<div class="controls">

  <button class="js-seralize">Serialize</button>
</div>

<textarea id="log"></textarea>

<div class="gridster">
  <ul>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><textarea class="textareaclass">ABC,DEF</textarea></li>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"><textarea class="textareaclass">ABC,Def ,D S C</textarea></li>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"><textarea class="textareaclass">ABC,DEF,X yz</textarea></li>
    <li data-row="3" data-col="2" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="1"><textarea class="textareaclass">BAC,ABC,XYZ</textarea></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) for webpage.I am getting a json variable which represents the widget position and html content on it as soon as I press [Serialize](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/serialize.html).But json does not gets updated if I write some new html content on the text area.It just takes the default content(content already declared in the body).I want the updated content in the JSON to be encoded as soon as i press serialize

The function which generates json variable with html content from textarea

```
$('.js-seralize').on('click', function () {
    var s = gridster.serialize();
    $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el)=>{ // grab the grid elements
       s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values
    });
    $('#log').val(JSON.stringify(s));
})

    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvt0hf7r/28/)
In the fiddle the json captures "ABC,DEF" from the widget 1 but when I write something like "BAC,ABC,YZX" it wont capture the updated content.I want it to capture it

**Update  1**
Please check this new fiddle having 38 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3crspqL5/38/)

Comment: This is the link https://jsfiddle.net/kvt0hf7r/28/

Comment: Sorry if the above question was not providing sufficient information

Comment: I have these links in my resources for fiddle :https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js and https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/dist/jquery.gridster.min.js

Comment: I think this is what you are talking of including in fiddle

Comment: Include those in the snippet, too. Snippet is always preferred way of demonstrating code.

Comment: Included the scripts in above snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [gridster's docs](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/#documentation), you can add a `serialize_params` to your gridster initialization to customize what the serialization does.

You can then add a `value` field that will get serialized as `$w.find(':input').val()` which retrieves the up-to-date value of the input field within each cell of the grid.

```js
gridster = $('.gridster ul').gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 55],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  serialize_params: function($w, wgd) { 
    return { 
      value: $w.find(':input').val(), 
      col: wgd.col, 
      row: wgd.row, 
      size_x: wgd.size_x, 
      size_y: wgd.size_y 
    } 
  }
}).data('gridster');
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v22o4wxv/7/)

Comment: Yes. I'll fork the fiddle next.

Comment: @NewBie Updated with a fiddle. The only difference is that the `value` field of the serialization contains the updated value of your input. (`html` is still there as the initial value.)

Comment: Can you provide link to fiddle I am not able to find it

Comment: @NewBie Bottom of answer.

Comment: This is awesome ! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166613/discussion-between-newbie-and-jeto).

Comment: Can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3crspqL5/40/ This is simulating exactly what I am doing