# Getting the value of HTML from serialize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) for webpage.I altered the basic [Serialize](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/serialize.html)  function to genearate a json which captures the HTML content of the widgets along with its bascic other parameters(row,col,size_x,size_y).This works fine when the widgets are already declared in the body section of HTML.But when I generate the widgets via JSON the content does not appear in the json obtained from serialize function.All other paramerterds(row,col,size_x,size_y) appear in both cases.

The basic serialize function is as follows

```
/**
 * Returns a serialized array of the widgets in the grid.
 *
 * @method serialize
 * @param {HTMLElement} [$widgets] The collection of jQuery wrapped
 *  HTMLElements you want to serialize. If no argument is passed all widgets
 *  will be serialized.
 * @return {Array} Returns an Array of Objects with the data specified in
 *  the serialize_params option.
 */
fn.serialize = function ($widgets) {
    $widgets || ($widgets = this.$widgets);
    var result = [];
    $widgets.each($.proxy(function (i, widget) {
        var $w = $(widget);
        if (typeof($w.coords().grid) !== 'undefined') {
            result.push(this.options.serialize_params($w, $w.coords().grid));
        }
    }, this));
    return result;
};
```

And serialize_params is as follows

```
serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
                    return {
                        col: wgd.col,
                        row: wgd.row,
                        size_x: wgd.size_x,
                        size_y: wgd.size_y
                    };
```

Which generates a json of following form

```
[{"col":1,"row":1,"size_x":2,"size_y":2}}
```

My new serialize function is of following nature which captures value and html from textarea tag with help of function to generate html key value pair

New serialize function generates "value" in json

```
gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
    serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
            return {value: $w.find(':input').val(), col: wgd.col, row: wgd.row, size_x: wgd.size_x, size_y: wgd.size_y}
        },
  helper: 'clone',
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');
```

Function that generates "HTML" key value pair

```
    $('.js-seralize').on('click', function() {
        var s = gridster.serialize();
        $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
            s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values
        });
        $('#log').val(JSON.stringify(s));
});
```

The new function generates json of following form

```
 [{"value":"","col":3,"row":6,"size_x":2,"size_y":2,"html":"Extracted text from textarea"}]
```

The "value" key appears blank for the widgets generated via JSON.But it is present when widgets are declared in body.

The "html" key appears in both cases(when declared in body and generated from json) but it is static(I mean if the content on widgets text area is changed in realtime then it still shows previous/original content only and wont update for new content)

I want the "value" key to be updated also when widgets are dynamically generated from JSON

In the fiddle you can see the "value" key in the JSON is updated/displayed only for widget declared in body section(It has textarea value"This will update if you type something new")
.For rest it is not even showing.The "html" key, which is a static, is shown perfect.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3crspqL5/47/)

Comment: I answered to you already after [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49217637/capturing-the-updated-content-from-text-are-in-json-variable/), [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166613/discussion-between-newbie-and-jeto).

Comment: I have mentioned the problem here(the value not getting captured from elements generated via JSON)

Comment: It is able to capture updated value for widgets in body

Comment: The "here" link on my comment points to [our chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166613/discussion-between-newbie-and-jeto).

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that.I have not got any notification from the chat we had

Comment: Will it be good to delete this question or you want to address it

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to notify, which is a shame. I'll post the answer below then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166623/discussion-between-newbie-and-jeto).

Comment: Can you please address my query in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your grid cells always contain textareas, change:

```
$w.find(':input').val()
```

into:

```
$w.find('textarea').val().trim()
```

(The former will also match  your button, which is why the `.val()` call didn't return the value you wanted.)