# Delete an image mapped to json in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widget for webpage.I have widgets which have images on them.There is a JSON which gives data about what image should be there on each grid(I get text from JSON and then get corresponding image from database).I want a button on each image which will delete the image from the widget and also remove the corresponding value from JSON.

My JS loop which generates widgets:

```
for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
            {% load static %}
       gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/'+json[index].html+'"></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
    };
```

My JSON

```
  var json = [{
            "html": 'abc.png',
            "col": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "size_y": 2,
            "size_x": 2
        }, {
            "html": "xyz.png", 
            "col": 4,
            "row": 1,
            "size_y": 2,
            "size_x": 2
        },

        {
            "html": "def.png",
            "col": 6,
            "row": 1,
            "size_y": 2,
            "size_x": 2
        },


        {
            "html": "abc.png",
            "col": 1,
            "row": 3,
            "size_y": 1,
            "size_x": 1
        }, {
            "html": "def.png",
            "col": 4,
            "row": 3,
            "size_y": 1,
            "size_x": 1
        },

        {
            "html": "abc.png    ",
            "col": 6,
            "row": 3,
            "size_y": 1,
            "size_x": 1
        }

        ];
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>

    </ul>

</div>
```

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2worw37s/) is what I am trying to do

The fiddle has a button to delete the image but it does not seem to work and after image is deleted I want to update/clear corresponding key value pair as well to json object from which it is generated

Any help will be really appreciated because this seems to be an advanced level topic of JS/Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.removediv').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
});
```

Tested here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2worw37s/8/)

Comment: I want to remove the image and not the outer widget

Comment: It removes the li element as well.I have put an "x" button which I want to remove the image

Comment: Is it deleting the image or just hiding it ?

Comment: replace `hide()` with `remove()`

Comment: Thanks this solves my one part of question.But other part is I also want to remove the JSON value from which it is getting generated.That is where I was not able to think at all

Comment: So when I generate the json again then it will have no value in "html" field where image is deleted

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/22530po8/1/ This will help you to understand how I am getting my JSON

Comment: Also this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220256/getting-the-value-of-html-from-serialize-function

Comment: I make use of serialize function to generate JSON.But I dont think that would work here.A new function which will generate JSON of similar form will be needed for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167397/discussion-between-newbie-and-codekaizer).

Comment: I just want to know how I can clear the value of "html" key when I delete an image for a particular widget This is what I was not understanding

Comment: `delete window.json[index]`, assuming `json` is a global var

Comment: I mean in the function which is in the answer above I want to also get the the widget from which the function is called.So that I can remove the "html" of that widget.I am not able to get how can I pass the which widgets is calling that function